# I want to insert tables with variable lengths into an sqlite database but I am getting an error stating: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

Because I want to insert tables with varying sizes I need to be able to use a string variable in my insert statement for example like so:

```
numvals = '?,?'
vals = 'delays_values[0], delays_values[1]'
converted_valz = 'ID int ,Description text'

c.execute("CREATE TABLE DELAYS ("+converted_valz+")")
c.execute("INSERT INTO DELAYS VALUES ("+numvals+" )", (vals))
```

However this gives me the aforementioned error which says exactly: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 19, and there are 349 supplied.

For some reason, if I replace vals with the hardcoded values it actually contains like so it actually works but then I am forced to hardcode values which defeats the purpose of all of this. Please help!:

```
numvals = '?,?'
vals = 'delays_values[0], delays_values[1]'
converted_valz = 'ID int ,Description text'

c.execute("CREATE TABLE DELAYS ("+converted_valz+")")
c.execute("INSERT INTO DELAYS VALUES ("+numvals+" )", (delays_values[0], delays_values[1]))
```

Comment: When i run your code I don't get that error i get a different error. I do see issues with your code but I just wanna make sure what the issue is. Can you please post the rest of your code and I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an oversimplification that may cause problems later on, but an easy fix is to evaluate your `vals` string with `eval(vals)` in the end:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()

delays_values = (1,2)

numvals = '?,?'
vals = 'delays_values[0], delays_values[1]'
converted_valz = 'ID int ,Description text'

c.execute("CREATE TABLE DELAYS ("+converted_valz+")")

c.execute("INSERT INTO DELAYS VALUES ("+numvals+" )", eval(vals))
```

Don't know why `vals` is a string to begin with though to be honest...

Comment: So this does fix it but it strips away some special characters. Better than nothing I guess! Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean strips away some special characters? What exactly do you want to do? Why is vals a string?

Comment: How else can I use the first line of a file to determine what my column headers will be for my SQL database? I want to pull the first row of an excel file and based on that row I want to create a table with columns that correspond with the correct variable type. So if it is | ID | Name | Date | then I want a table with three columns to be created and the first column have type int, the second column have type string and the third column have type int.

Comment: So is vals = the first row of this Excel file?